# ¿Cómo limitar el numero de repeticiones de una columna en MySQL o cómo obtener un único valor?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo el siguiente query

```sql
SELECT
  c.cot_id, cb.*
FROM cot as c
LEFT JOIN cot_bit AS cb ON cb.cot_father_id = c.cot_id;
```

El cual produce la siguiente salida.

```
| cot_id | cot_bit_id | cot_father_id | cot_children_id |
|--------|------------|---------------|-----------------|
|      1 |          1 |             1 |               4 |
|      1 |          2 |             1 |               5 |
|      1 |          3 |             1 |               6 |
|      7 |          4 |             7 |               8 |
|      7 |          5 |             7 |               9 |
|      7 |          6 |             7 |              10 |
|      7 |          7 |             7 |              11 |
|      7 |          8 |             7 |              12 |
|      2 |       NULL |          NULL |            NULL |
|      3 |       NULL |          NULL |            NULL |
```

La columna `cot_id` se repite con el mismo valor múltiples veces, pero me interesa que salga una sola vez. Por ejemplo:

Quisiera pasar del resultado original a esto:

```
| cot_id | cot_bit_id | cot_father_id | cot_children_id |
|--------|------------|---------------|-----------------|
|      1 |          3 |             1 |               6 |
|      7 |          8 |             7 |              12 |
|      2 |       NULL |          NULL |            NULL |
|      3 |       NULL |          NULL |            NULL |
```

Para tener un único valor por valor de `cot_id`.

¿Qué puedo incluir en mi query para lograr evitar estas repeticiones?

Answer (score 0):

Agrupa por `c.cot_id` selecciona el valor máximo de las otras columnas:

```
SELECT
  c.cot_id, MAX(cot_bit_id) as cot_bit_id, MAX(cot_father_id) as cot_father_id,
  MAX(cot_children_id) as cot_children_id
FROM cot as c
LEFT JOIN cot_bit AS cb ON cb.cot_father_id = c.cot_id
GROUP BY c.cot_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Tendrías que especificar qué tipo de valor quieres de las demás columnas. @crrlos te ofrece el máximo de las otras, yo te propongo cualquiera con `any_value`

```
SELECT
    c.cot_id,
    any_value(cot_bit_id),
    any_value(cot_father_id),
    any_value(cot_children_id)
FROM cot as c
LEFT JOIN cot_bit AS cb
    ON cb.cot_father_id = c.cot_id
GROUP BY c.cot_id;
```